# Execute PHP file via Ajax in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

When I place this code in functions.php it displays the nr of products next to the cart icon. IT WORKS WELL when in functions.php

But because im using a a caching plugin I can't include the code in functions.php or have to somehow exclude the code execution from the cache.

I think the best way would with Ajax jQuery. Is there a better way??

This is the code below that I now place in a file called cartbubble.php , it is as so :

```
<?
function my_wc_cart_count() 
{
  if (in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))) 
  {     
    $count = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count; ?>
    <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart'); ?>">
      <?php if ( $count >= 0 ) { ?>
        <span class="cart-contents-count"><?php echo esc_html( $count ); ?></span>
      <?php } ?>
    </a>
    <?php
  }
}

add_action('woo_header_inside', 'my_wc_cart_count');

function my_header_add_to_cart_fragment($fragments) 
{
  ob_start();
  if ($count >= 0) 
  { ?>
    <span class="cart-contents-count"><?php echo WC()->cart->cart_contents_count(); ?></span>
    <?php 
  } ?>

  <?php
    $fragments['span.cart-contents-count'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $fragments;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'my_header_add_to_cart_fragment');
```

Here's what I used in header.php to call it via ajax jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: '/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/cartbubble.php',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);.
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log('error');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Why is it not executing the function is the same way as it does in functions.php??

Thanks in advance

Comment: The end </script> i meant , failed to show in the post

Comment: It's because the formatting of your code in the question wasn't quite right. I've fixed it for you, although note that you have an extra `.` in the JS (after the `console.log`) which will be causing a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is your approach. The `cartbubble.php` file is not loading WordPress first so the functions you are calling are not available. The `functions.php` file is called in all normal loading of the front and back ends of WordPress so full functionality is available to you in there.

You can still use AJAX in your `functions.php` file in the manner below. There are special actions for AJAX in WordPress that allow you to use it more easily.

First you need to attach a function to your AJAX hook like so...

```
// This will hook into both logged in and anonymous visitors
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_header_cart_count', 'my_header_cart_count' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_header_cart_count', 'my_header_cart_count' );

function my_header_cart_count()
{
    echo WC()->cart->cart_contents_count();
    wp_die();
}
```

You should also use code to inject your JS into the footer...

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_header_cart_javascript' );

function my_header_cart_javascript() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var data = {
            'action': 'my_header_cart_count'
        };

        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            // Inject the response into the containing span
            $('.cart-contents-count').html(response);
        });
    });
    </script> <?php
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I added exactly what you provided. Unfortunately the number in the span still remains cached and doesnt update. I get the following error in the console :

Comment: (index):651 Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxurl is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):651)
    at i (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js:2)

Comment: To try to fix this "ajax Url is not defined", I added this to functions.php : add_action('wp_head', 'myplugin_ajaxurl');

function myplugin_ajaxurl() {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           var ajaxurl = "' . admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '";
         </script>';
}

Comment: Console says the server responded with a status of 500()   /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php:1      Thanks in Advance , I feel Im really close to make this work

Comment: IT IS WORKING ! @BA_Webimax, Thank you very much - I had to change - echo WC()->cart->cart_contents_count(); TO echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); Now it's working great! Thanks Again!

Comment: when i am trying to execute a php file located on server i am getting CORS error. .. can someone help what should i use to fix this error. i tried using headers while sending request.|

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/abclocation/scriptExecutor.php' from origin 'http://localhost:8083' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https